# Using IPBoard's default database abstraction class

Tags: php, database, ipb

I would like to use IPBoard's [classDb](http://community.invisionpower.com/resources/documentation/index.html/_/developer-resources/api-methods/classdb-r340), but my server keeps responding with error (there is nothing to quote, it's a generic text, that I couldn't communicate with DB).

How to properly configure my IPBoard environment to make classDb work?

```
$results = array();

$this->DB->build(array('select' => '*', 'from' => 'names'));

//here code fails
$this->DB->execute();

//(...)
```

(mysql_* works fine)

Comment: > //here code fails : what is the error message?

Comment: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24503324/static/ipboard-classDb.png

Comment: I mean, don't you have a more informative error somewhere in your log? No exception is thrown? What is your current config?

Comment: @bpgergo: damn me. I just looked into logs and there's an answer.. With default configuration, every table has to have 'ipb_' prefix. classDb adds it before executing.

Comment: cool :) maybe you could post what was the error or close this anyway.

Comment: I'll close question after I post full answer, not only for default configuration.